# Building a desktop app using ParaView API under the hood

Tags: paraview

I have this workflow with ParaView where I

```
1) load a dicom, 
2) load a state where I perform actions on the dicom (sources, filters, custom filters, etc). 
3) apply a custom macro where I initialize everything.
```

Then I have some custom macros that moves lines in the final result.

I would like to make a desktop app with a simple UI where a I have one button that executes the 3 necessary steps to initialize everything. And then I have three buttons that executes the custom macros.

So I'm basically making a simpler ParaView.

I have used the trace function that ParaView has to make a python script with all the steps and then executing them in the pvpython shell to test if I reach the same result that in the ParaView GUI.

But a simple script that just load the dicom makes the windows `(Visualization Toolkit - Win320OpenGL)` not responding.

What do you think is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is fully supported by ParaView, as ParaView is not only an application but also a framework.

This is documented here : https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Writing_Custom_Applications

Examples are in ParaView code : https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/tree/master/Examples/CustomApplications

For follow-up questions, I would suggest asking on the ParaView Discourse : https://discourse.paraview.org/

Comment: Great! And this custom application can be made with pyside or pyqt?

Comment: Nope, this is made for C++ Application. It is possible to work in pyqt but you will not have access to all the framework.